# Strange Google Map Behavior - Tiles Appear Only In Upper Left Quadrant

Tags: google-maps, browser

Have used google maps dozens of times but cannot get around this one. Doing google's simple hello world for map version 3 (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#api_key)

However the tiles only appear in the upper left part of the map canvas and even when dragging / scrolling they continue to stay in the upper-left. See pic: http://sandbox.thecanarycollective.com/whiteboard/2012-03-05_073019.png

I have played with the CSS on the page quite a bit to see if it was getting screwed up by something else but no luck. Anyone ever see this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The individual tiles are `div` elements. Try turning off the css on your page and see if this problem still occurs. Then use a tool like firebug to examine the HTML of the page - see if the missing tiles appear in the HTML.

Using firebug, write this into the console:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(googleMap, 'resize');
```

where `googleMap` is the map element. This may fix things if you're resizing the map after it is created.

If none of these help, post your javascript, css and HTML - its hard to think of what to suggest when you just provide a fixed image.