# Why is my Google Map in a jQuery UI tab only displaying one tile at the top left corner of the screen?

Tags: jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-tabs, interaction

I have two Google Map API v3 Maps in jQuery tabs. They both display the first time they appear in their tabs, but the initially deselected tab only displays a tile or so at the top left-hand corner.

Calling google.maps.event.trigger(all_map, 'resize') periodically does not change this.

In my code I have:

```
            <div id='all_map_canvas'>
            </div>
            <script>
                function show_all_map()
                    {
                    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(%(center_latitude)s - .15, %(center_longitude)s + .2);
                    var myoptions = {
                        zoom: %(zoom)s,
                        center: center,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                        };
                    all_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('all_map_canvas'), myoptions);
                    all_map.setZoom(%(zoom)s);
                    jQuery('#all_map_canvas').show();
                    google.maps.event.trigger(all_map, 'resize');
                    }
                function show_all_map_markers()
                    {
                    %(all_map_markers)s
                    }
                var markers = [];
                jQuery('#all_map_canvas').width(jQuery(window).width() -    300);
                jQuery('#all_map_canvas').height(jQuery(window).height() -  125);
```

How can I make both maps display in full after tab swaps?

Comment: Have you ever been able to solve this issue?

Comment: I called google.maps.event.trigger(all_map, 'resize'), repeated because the map was not originally displayed and I'm not sure how much it would help with stuff initialized to display: none.

Comment: +1 I'm having this exact bug, and `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` does nothing to get the map displaying more tiles.

Comment: Related, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566753/strange-google-map-behavior-tiles-appear-only-in-upper-left-quadrant

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem: Google map in div that has style `display:none;`.
Solved it with this two steps:

1. Removing all additional styling of the div I'm placing the map except `height:100%;`
2. Initiate the map after the holding div is displayed not when the it is created. In my case in the callback function of the show method:

   **CSS**

   ```
   .main-window #map{
       height:100%;
   }
   ```

   **JS**

   ```
   $('.main-window').show(3000, function() {
       // create the map after the div is displayed
       var mapOptions = {
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.499591, 27.474961),
           zoom: 8,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       };
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
   });
   ```

   **HTML**

   ```
   <div class="main-window">
       <div id="map"></div>
   </div>
   ```

Initiating it in events like jQuery's '$(document).ready(...' or Google's 'google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", ...' is not working for some reason.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [gmaps.js](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/) which is a simplified api for google map. But it's simply a matter of attaching a tabsshow event in javascript and refreshing the map in the delegate's function.

Here's the code I use for gmaps.js

```
$('#tabs').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (ui.panel.id == "tabs2") {
            //gmaps.js method
            map.refresh();
            map.setCenter(lastLoc.lat(), lastLoc.lng()); 

            //for native google.maps api
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lastLoc.lat(), lastLoc.lng()));            
    }
});
```

Comment: You may need to unpick what `map.refresh()` actually does, because it's not a native function.

Comment: I'd also like to know what map.refresh() does.