# Where do I put this line of JS for my Google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the following code to create an embedded Google map on my webpage:

```
function init() {
    var mapOptions = {                                 // Set up the map options
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.782710,-73.965310),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 13
    };
    var venueMap;                                      // Map() draws a map
    venueMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');     // Create <script> element
    script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=init';
    document.body.appendChild(script);                 // Add element to page
}

window.onload = loadScript;                          // on load call loadScript()
```

It works well, except it creates the same error [described here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566753/strange-google-map-behavior-tiles-appear-only-in-upper-left-quadrant) A simple suggested solution was to add the following line:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

One user suggests putting it in the console and when I do that, it works great. Even if I manually readjust the size of the window, it resets perfectly. I tried to insert the code right after the line that adds the element to the page and I get an error from Firefox that says `ReferenceError: google is not defined` and points to the line I inserted.

Where should I be putting this code?

EDIT: Here's the code that recreates the problem:

```js
$(function() {
  $("article").hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);

  loadScript();

  google.maps.event.listener(map, 'resize');

});

function init() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.782710, -73.965310),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoom: 13
  };
  var venueMap;
  venueMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  //google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=init';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

```css
#map {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
article {
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  <div id="map"></div>
  <script src="js/google-map.js"></script>
</article>
```

Comment: Does your HTML give the div with id="map" a percentage size or something that doesn't have a size? Is it (the div with id="map") hidden on page load (that means it has zero size on page load)? If either of those is true, that is the problem, not where the script is run.  [Working fiddle using the posted code](http://jsfiddle.net/hse6bx9t/)

Comment: @geocodezip I didn't think about that, but sure enough. I have a line of JS that hides the main body of the webpage on launch, then fades it in. If I comment that and reload, the map works fine, but I'd like to keep that feature if possible. The line I use is `$("article, footer").not("#home").hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);`. Is there anything I can do to keep that effect while not having to use the work-around suggested in the OP?

Comment: Then what you need to do is trigger the resize event once the "fadeIn" completes.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the resize event (`google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');`) once your fadeIn completes and the div with id="map" has a size.

Comment: So that line needs to be put after the line `document.body.appendChild(script); ` in the `loadScript()` function?

Comment: No.  In the FadeIn complete function (or sometime thereafter).

Comment: How can I do this if I use a separate script to initialize the map? I use two separate scripts to load the map and fade in all of the items.

Comment: You didn't post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question, so it is hard to say.

Comment: Sorry about that. [Here's a link](http://jsbin.com/voxeleyazo/3/edit?html,js,output) to the JSbin.

Comment: Please post the relevant code (preferably a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not a dump of everything), in the question itself, not on an external site (the question should stand alone if the link is dead).